# SQL Server Auto Number is not increasing properly?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core-3.1

I am using SQL Server 2019 with Asp.Net Core 3.1.

I reset the data increment to start from 1.

Data is being entered, and the number is increasing. But sometimes it goes from `ID = 56` to `Id = 154`, or from `ID = 126` to `ID = 1124`.

Comment: check your code, you do it wrong, also do you have read that similar answer -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47791479/sql-server-primary-key-id-does-not-increment-correctly

Comment: So you get gaps in your id's, why do you care?

Comment: maybe this article is the answer ? https://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/how-to-eliminate-gaps-in-identity-values-in-sql-server-by-disabling-the-identity-cache.html

Comment: @HoneyBadger, Just to make sure it is nothing went wrong in the future

Comment: any possible way to ensure it is increasing properly.

Comment: It ***IS*** increasing properly - the **only** guarantee you get from SQL Server is that the values are **increasing** - and they are. There are no other guarantees given.

Comment: I use this "ALTER DATABASE SCOPED CONFIGURATION SET IDENTITY_CACHE=OFF;" hope this help

Comment: `IDENTITY` is working exactly as it's meant to be. Nothing in `IDENTITY` states the values will be sequential and the process is, and gaps occurring is by design. If you want sequential values `IDENTITY` is not the correct choice. turning `IDENTITY_CACHE` off can help, however, it does come with performance considerations.

Comment: Let me just put this here... [SQL Server’s identity column misconceptions](https://zoharpeled.wordpress.com/2019/10/06/sql-servers-identity-column-misconceptions/)